# Cannot open Spyder in Anaconda Navigator in Linux Mint 18.2 Cinnamon 64-bit

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, anaconda, spyder

I installed and updated Anaconda. I opened Anaconda Navigator, and I clicked the "Launch" button for Spyder 4.1.2. I got this error message. How do I fix this?

```
QApplication: invalid style override passed, ignoring it.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/monica/anaconda3/bin/spyder", line 11, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "/home/monica/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 205, in main
mainwindow.main()
File "/home/monica/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 3734, in main
mainwindow = run_spyder(app, options, args)
File "/home/monica/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 3590, in run_spyder
main.setup()
File "/home/monica/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 977, in setup
'spyder.plugins.{}'.format(plugin_name))
File "/home/monica/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "", line 728, in exec_module
File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/monica/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/plugins/pylint/__init__.py", line 14, in 
from .plugin import Pylint as PLUGIN_CLASS
File "/home/monica/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/plugins/pylint/plugin.py", line 29, in 
from spyder.plugins.pylint.confpage import PylintConfigPage
File "/home/monica/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/plugins/pylint/confpage.py", line 16, in 
from spyder.plugins.pylint.widgets.pylintgui import PylintWidget
File "/home/monica/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/plugins/pylint/widgets/pylintgui.py", line 37, in 
from spyder.plugins.pylint.utils import get_pylintrc_path
File "/home/monica/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/plugins/pylint/utils.py", line 16, in 
import pylint.config
File "/home/monica/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pylint/config.py", line 54, in 
import toml
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'toml'
[1:1:0100/000000.664265:ERROR:broker_posix.cc(41)] Invalid node channel message
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After A LOT of searching on Google, I found a solution.

https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/12557

I ran the code

```
conda install toml spyder=4.1.2
```

This worked!

Comment: Same problem on Windows-10 64 bit. But your fix works.
Thanks